# How to list YAML pipelines with deployment jobs using Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm looking for a way to list all YAML Pipelines "definition" that trigger deployments using the [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) feature (released in [GA](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-general-availability-of-azure-pipelines-yaml-cd/) in 2020).

In previous [Classic Release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops), it was easy, you just had to list all existing release definitions pipelines using the [release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST API endpoint:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0
```

I didn't find anything similar with YAML Pipelines.

I tried using the [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) endpoint (released in REST API version 6.0) to get pipeline information:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Returning this JSON (redacted):

```
    {
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/19d42339-19ab-0000-aa1c-3f8e53300000/_apis/pipelines/1813?revision=2"
            },
            "web": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/19d42339-19ab-0000-aa1c-3f8e53300000/_build/definition?definitionId=1813"
            }
        },
        "configuration": {
            "path": "azure-pipelines/CI.yml",
            "repository": {
                "id": "a5e1ea98-1181-40a0-932f-6fcbdb92b1a0",
                "type": "azureReposGit"
            },
            "type": "yaml"
        },
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/19d42339-19ab-0000-aa1c-3f8e53300000/_apis/pipelines/1813?revision=2",
        "id": 1813,
        "revision": 2,
        "name": "My YAML Pipeline definition",
        "folder": "\\"
    }
```

You get the repository and YAML file used to create this pipeline, but no information about the content. There is no way to know this pipeline is used for deployments.

Using Azure DevOps REST API, is there a way to retrieve more information about a YAML pipeline to be able to know if it will be involved in deployments ?

PS: Downloading YAML files and parsing them to get deployment job references is NOT an option.

Comment: Related question about missing features in YAML Pipelines used for deployment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108530/how-to-be-notified-about-a-deployment-done-in-yaml-pipelines-using-azure-devops/66115257

Comment: Are the following replies helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you can't use any of the available APIs to retrieve YAML pipelines associated with releases.

The best I can offer for advice in that regard is to do one of two things to be able to easily detect if a pipeline both builds & deploys, or just builds:

1. Update the naming conventions of your YAML pipelines to include a suffix that indicates what the purpose of the pipeline is. **For Example:** My Pipeline - Release & My Pipeline - Build
2. Organize your folders to include a Build and Release folder within your pipeline hierarchy.

If you use either of those options, you'll be able to easily detect if a pipeline is deploying within a script.

Answer (score 0):

> How to list YAML pipelines with deployment jobs using Azure DevOps REST API?

Indeed, there is no such out of box way to list YAML pipelines with deployment jobs using Azure DevOps REST API.

But we could use the REST API [Yaml - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/yaml/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/yaml?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

One thing to note is that response body is not a standard YAML format, we can simply transform it:

```
$outfile = "D:\YAMLTempFolder\test.yaml"

$connectionToken="Your PAT Here"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::  

ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$YAMLURL = "GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/yaml?api-version=6.1-preview.1"   

$YAMLInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $YAMLURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 

$yaml = $YAMLInfo.yaml

echo $yaml.Replace("...","") > $outfile
```

The test result of my YAML file is:

[image]

Now, we only need to determine whether the file contains keywords `-deployment`.

Comment: Thank your for answer.
I'm not sure I (or anyone else) would want to write a YAML parser (and keep it up to date) to be able to have a needs as simple as listing deployment job. 
YAML Template usage make this harder than you might expect. At least, if the YAML parser used by Azure DevOps would be publicly available that wouldn't much of an issue, but it doesn't seems to be the case.

In my opinion, it's seems to be a basic feature that the product should have: as explained in my question, it was easy with classic pipelines. Why should it be so hard with such "modern" feature ?